# Why is the submitted text from my textarea rendering as a single line?

Tags: php, html

I'm not sure what the problem is, but if I type in my textarea while holding down a single key on my keyboard, the output from my database will render as a single line  that breaks the formatting of my page. Essentially I just have one long line of text like `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa` that goes off the page and does not have any line breaks.

In other words, if I don't manually type `enter` to create a line break in my textarea, or if I don't use the `spacebar` to write something that appears to be a normal sentence, no line breaks will exist even though the textarea pushes the text down a line as I'm typing it.

I've tried this with a vanilla PHP script, filtering none of my content (I've also made sure not to filter anything when rendering the text), and this still happens. Why is this? Is there a way for me to make sure my textarea automatically adds new lines as it pushes text down when typing?

I am not using `cols` or `rows` in my HTML, but rather generated the height and width via CSS.

HTML:

```
<form action="foo.php" method="post">
    <textarea id="1"></textarea>                                   
    <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Comment" />
</form>
```

CSS:

```
#1 {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 126px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: hidden;
    resize: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: black;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    padding: 4px 8px;
    border: 2px solid #0716a2;
    border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
}
```

It may also be helpful to mention that this occurs when copy and pasting text that isn't formatted (i.e. not from a site like [this](https://lipsum.com/)). My textarea should be able to accommodate multiple paragraphs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds to me like the text is simply being rendered quite normally.

Check out the following bits of HTML that have the following CSS:

```
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 400px;
}
```

This bit of HTML:

```
<div>
  aaaaaa
</div>
```

Renders:

[image: 6 "a"s being rendered in a <div>]

However, this:

```
<div>
  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
</div>
```

Renders this:

[image: 108 "a"s in a <div>]

But, this:

```
<div>
  aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa
</div>
```

Renders this:

[image: 108 "a"s in a <div>, but split into words of length 6]

It's quite standard. However, if you want to fix this, you can add the following style:

```
overflow-wrap: break-word;
```

And this will cause the long words to break up, like so (with some extra filler text to show how it doesn't break the other words unnecessarily):

[image: Using overflow-wrap break-word on 108 "a"s, with some filler text]

I hope that helps.

Comment: You just saved my night. Do you know if `word-wrap` is compatible in most modern browsers?

Comment: @Dalsia This should answer your question. `overflow-wrap` is just an alias for `word-wrap`. https://caniuse.com/#search=overflow-wrap